Definition of four-potential in lattice gauge theory
In Wen's book 'Quantum Field Theory of Many Body Systems' at chapter 6.4, he defines scalar potential on lattice sites while vector potential at lattice links in two dimensional square lattice. What is the reason behind the potentials' definitions on lattice sites or links? Is it something related with holonomy, i.e. Wegner-Wilson loop? I will appreciate any explanation.
